# Delphi Region compiler directive - backwards compatible unit files?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, region

Given the desire to use the useful Region compiler directive in unit files, what's the best approach to allow these same units from being used in previous versions of Delphi?  There doesn't seem to be a 'decent' approach. (Desired IDE version is Delphi 7)

I like having Regions above the method definitions to hide/display the method definition help and version history comments but I'd have to surround the Region directives with other compiler directives, which kinda kills the 'cleaness' of region compiler directives.

I suppose a preprocessor could be written to comment out all Region/EndRegion directives if using a version of Delphi which doesn't support regions..and add then back for later versions?

I'm not 100% switched to Delphi 2009 and need to support multiple IDE versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming D7 doesn't want to copile {$REGION} or {$ENDREGION}? I only have D2007/9 installed and cannot check that.

Try this:

```
{$IFDEF undef}{$REGION 'bla'}{$ENDIF}
//some code
{$IFDEF undef}{$ENDREGION}{$ENDIF}
```

D2009 editor creates a region as expected. D7 should ignore the $REGION/$ENDREGION if 'undef' is not defined.

Comment: +1. Put on one line, and created with a code or live template this does  neither kill cleanliness, nor is it more effort to write.

Comment: This works...and will mark as the answer, as mentioned in the original question.  My real answer is to remove Regions for now and switch everything to 2009 as time permits.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few Delphi(7) editor-enhancement-components out there, that provide something like this. I think [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) does.

If you're ok with an impact on your code,  you might consider {$I } to split large files.

Comment: ... or just split the unit into several units!
About $INCLUDE directive use, from my experiment, $I does not work well in the Delphi IDE. For instance, the code navigator has issues browsing the code in included files. There is no problem with the compiler, but with the Delphi IDE. On the contrary, Lazarus has no issue when using several $INCLUDEd files, and handle them just as regular .pas files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
{$IF CompilerVersion >= 17} // The $REGION directive is available since Delphi 2005
{$REGION 'RegionName'}
{$ENDIF} 

// codeblock

{$IF CompilerVersion >= 17} 
{$ENDREGION 'RegionName'}
{$ENDIF}
```